# How to remove multiple items from an array via looping in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I have a javascript array of multiple values:

```
var keymap = {'name': 'foobaz', 
              'mappings': [{'id': 1, 'key': 'b'},
                          {'id': 2, 'key': 'c'},
                          {'id': 3, 'key': 'd'},
                          {'id': 1, 'key': 'e'},
                          {'id': 10, 'key': 'f'},
                          {'id': 7, 'key': 'g'},
                          {'id': 1, 'key': 'h'}]
}
```

I want to remove any entries where key is 'b'. Note the ids correspond to the backend ids. What I want to do is to remove some of the mappings (for example, all with 'id' as '1').

What I've tried is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < keymap['mappings'].length; i++) {
    if (keymap['mappings'][i]['id'] === id_to_match) {
        keyboard_map['mappings'].splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

However, slice will change the indexes of the array in-place, and therefore now `i` won't point to the correct index point (as any indexes higher will now be `i-n` where `n` would be the number of slices done before.

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is to decrement the iterator (this works since you read the length every iteration - so make sure you avoid caching the length)

```
for (var i = 0; i < keymap['mappings'].length; i++) {
 if (keymap['mappings'][i]['id'] === id_to_match) {
    keyboard_map['mappings'].splice(i, 1);
    i--;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var id_to_remove = 1;
keymap.mappings = keymap.mappings.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id !== id_to_remove;
}));
```

Notice that, besides using the `filter` method or not, even with a plain `for` loop, is much better for performance create a new array from scratch, instead of mutate the current one multiple times. So basically:

```
var id_to_remove = 1;
var filtered = [];
for (var i = 0, item; item = keymap.mappings[i++];) {
    if (item.id !== id_to_remove)
        filtered.push(item);
}
keymap.mappings = filtered;
```

Of course if `filter` is available it's much better use it because it's native, here we just mimic the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < keymap['mappings'].length; i++) {
    if (keymap['mappings'][i]['id'] === id_to_match) {
        keyboard_map['mappings'].splice(i--, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could walk your array backwards, so that the splicing doesn't impact later loop iterations:

```
for (var i = keymap['mappings'].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (keymap['mappings'][i]['id'] === id_to_match) {
        keyboard_map['mappings'].splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "filter" method like this:

```
keymap.mappings = keymap.mappings.filter(function(element){
    return element.id != 1;
});
```

Which means "keep only elements with id different than 1" or same result "remove elements with id equal to 1".

Every browser implement it, except IE8.
http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.filter