# Shortest way of looping over an array and creating a new one with values omitted?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

In a lot of my code I do something like:

```
return routes.map(route => processValue(route.someProperty));
```

To quickly return a new array with only the processed data I need. However in its current form if you don't return anything the new array will have an `undefined` value for the index where that `map()` ran the function on the original array's element.

I was wondering if there is a similar, quick way to implement something mixed with a `.map()` and a `filter()`, where the new array only has the elements returned from the callback function?

Comment: possible duplicate(s): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520662/how-to-remove-multiple-items-from-an-array-via-looping-in-javascript | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439015/javascript-filter-array-of-objects-based-on-property-values

Comment: *"where the new array only has the elements returned from the callback function"* -> `routes.filter(route => route.someProperty === processValue(route.someProperty));` of course, that would fail if the "elements" weren't simple values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce`:

```
return routes.reduce((acc, route) => {
  const value = processValue(route.someProperty);
  if (value !== undefined) acc.push(value);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

or even smaller, as long as `processValue` doesn't return an array:

```
return routes.reduce((acc, route) => acc.concat(processValue(route.someProperty) || [], []);
```

Personally I like `.map().filter` though as

```
return routes
  .map((route) => processValue(route.someProperty))
  .filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: I really should've given the `reduce()` documentation a longer look, I completely misunderstood it at first glance. The shorthand form of `reduce` is a little messy but both are still cool. Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas of the performance differences between using reduce and say, a for loop while pushing the values to a predefined var?

Comment: I personally prefer the filter method, much cleaner.

Comment: Better be explicit about `if (value != null)` to filter out nulls and undefined values, but not other falsy primitives.

Comment: iIf there's a possibility of those in your dataset then you definitely should. Code should always be explicit. Which is why I prefer the filter method. It's less ambiguous.

Comment: Dang these downvotes are harsh...

Comment: people are trolls... worst part about SO.